# Compare a string by giving two possibilities for each character in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I need to compare a string by giving two possibilities for each character in the string in an (if) statement eg:

```
let str = "2 3 1 2"
if str == "(1||2) (2||3) (1||2) (1||2)" {
//Do Something
}
```

I know the code is not written correctly, but just to understand what I mean.

I used to use (Like Operator) in VB eg:

```
Dim s As String = "2 3 1 2"
If s Like "[1-2] [3-4] [2-3] [1-2]" Or s Like "[1-2] [1-2] [2-3] 2"  Then
//Do something
End If
```

I couldn't find anything similar in swift.

Please help, Thank you.